# Ubuntu with Gnome desktop - navigation using keyboard only

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, system-settings, navigation

The context of the question is that I'm **learning to navigate Ubuntu** with Gnome desktop, **using mainly the keyboard.** I'm no fanatic about it, but I'm trying to **move away from mouse navigation** towards keyboard navigation when it makes sense.

Here I'm in the Gnome's Settings app and I've entered few letters `keyb`. It looks like this:

[image]

### The Question

Providing the cursor is in the search box, like shown above, **how to move between the `search box` and the `search results` using only the keyboard?**

#### What I've tried

1. After single <kbd>Tab</kbd> press, the cursor disappears completely.
   No amount of up, down, left and right arrows pressing makes it
   reappear anywhere.
2. After double <kbd>Tab</kbd> press, the cursor
   appears in the right pane, highlighting the first, uppermost option.

Comment: If you mostly want to use the keyboard, a tiling window manager might suit your needs better https://bence.ferdinandy.com/2021/01/12/more-keyboard-less-mouse-my-regolith-tmux-vim-based-workflow/

Comment: Is tiling window manager a substitute for Gnome desktop??

Comment: Gnome in not meant for keyboard only operation. Tiling window managers work great with keyboard.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Overall, Gnome can be very well used with keyboard only, and in area' s where is is lacking (e.g. reaching the settings menu), it is improving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, hitting <kbd>↓</kbd> brings the rectangle over the search results. An <kbd>Enter</kbd> is needed to update the right pane, then hitting <kbd>→</kbd> moves the selection to the right pane.

This is on Gnome 45.2. On Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome 42.9, it rather goes as you describe, i.e., keyboard navigation does not work and is broken. So this is something that was fixed recently. One can rightfully wonder why it took 13 years to implement decent keyboard navigation in that tool, but here we are.

Another lesson learned is that, when asking questions, it is very important to also specify the version of Ubuntu you are using.